# Pros and cons for using external libraries in android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know what are pros and cons for using external libraries like [these](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries) in application development.

It is possible using these libraries application may run well on one device but may not run on any other device, application performance, size of apk using these library?

And which one is good idea while developing application in Android studio to copy file in libs folder or add it in dependencies and stay connected to internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell the pros and cons when using an external library in Android app development. Most of the time, it depends on the real circumstance. If the library simplify your app development and it's specially optimized for Android, it's worth to try.

When it comes performance about external library, the [document](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#ExternalLibs) says we should be careful.

As put libraries in `libs` directory or referencing them from `mavencenter`/`jcenter` repository, the result is the same. It will be compiled to your app by android app tools finally. In order to simplify your life, referencing the libraries from an internet repository is a better choice. You don't have to worry the version and dependencies. Android studio now has adopted this way.